GraphQL - Java RestTemplate
We are facing the odd issue in graphQL which is used in NexarAPI. For me, it is working fine while sending setting basic query
{  "query": "query Categories { supCategories { id name path }}"}

and content type set as application/json. We are able to retrieve the data from Altium with this query
But if we specify workspace and other stuff in the query
{ "query": "query design2_Library { desLibrary (workspaceUrl: "test") { components { nodes { id name manufacturerParts { partNumber companyName } details { parameters { name value } } } } } }" }

It throws the error as:

<200,{"errors":[{"message":"Expected a String-token, but found a Name-token.","locations":[{"line":1,"column":64}],"extensions":{"code":"HC0011"}}]},[Date:"Fri, 21 Jun 2024 11:16:40 GMT", Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Server:"Kestrel", Cache-Control:"proxy-revalidate", X-SYMC-Transaction-UUID:"8b74d844d6cf25c1-000000000b3ff64b-0000000066756118", Connection:"keep-alive"]>

Even I tried with changing the content type to graphql, but it throws a 404 error during that. Please share your suggestion on this case and find below source code:
public String getComponent(String query) {
    logger.info("getComponent {Query:" + query + "}");
    try {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Map token = generateOAuthAcessToken(initContext, "QA");
        String url = nexarEndPoint;
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).queryParam("partNo", query);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(
            Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.valueOf("application/graphql-response+json") }));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/graphql-response+json"));
        // headers.setContentType(customMediaType);
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.get("access_token"));

        String alternateQuery = "{\"query\":\"query design2_Library { desLibrary (workspaceUrl: \\\"<altium workspace url>\\\") { components { nodes { id name manufacturerParts { partNumber companyName } details { parameters { name value } } } } } }\",\"variables\":{}}";
        query = "{  \"query\": \"query Categories { supCategories { id name path }}\"}";
        String graphqlQuery = "{ \"query\": \"query design2_Library { desLibrary (workspaceUrl: \"test\") { components { nodes { id name manufacturerParts { partNumber companyName } details { parameters { name value } } } } } }\" }";
        // String graphqlQuery1 = "{ \"query\": \"query design2_Library { desLibrary

        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(query.toString(), headers);
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        String result = response.getBody();
        JSONArray resultArr = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("desLibrary")                  .getJSONObject("components").getJSONArray("nodes");
        return resultArr.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Search value " + query + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
        return "Error : " + ex.getMessage();
    }
}


Query
Your second query example seems to miss escaping of the ticks around your workspaceUrl value "test". This becomes visible when formatting it as a json code block:
{ "query": "query design2_Library { desLibrary (workspaceUrl: "test") { components { nodes { id name manufacturerParts { partNumber companyName } details { parameters { name value } } } } } }" }

If this is the actual query you sent, then you probably just need to escape the ticks:
{ "query": "query design2_Library { desLibrary (workspaceUrl: \"test\") { components { nodes { id name manufacturerParts { partNumber companyName } details { parameters { name value } } } } } }" }

Code
The query corresponds to graphqlQueryin your code:
String graphqlQuery = "{ \"query\": \"query design2_Library { desLibrary (workspaceUrl: \"test\") { components { nodes { id name manufacturerParts { partNumber companyName } details { parameters { name value } } } } } }\" }";

Comparing this to your alternateQuery, we can see double escaping of the workspaceUrl value:
String alternateQuery = "{\"query\":\"query design2_Library { desLibrary (workspaceUrl: \\\"<altium workspace url>\\\") { components { nodes { id name manufacturerParts { partNumber companyName } details { parameters { name value } } } } } }\",\"variables\":{}}";

Have you tried adding more escapes on graphqlQuery around "test"?
String graphqlQuery = "{ \"query\": \"query design2_Library { desLibrary (workspaceUrl: \\\"test\\\") { components { nodes { id name manufacturerParts { partNumber companyName } details { parameters { name value } } } } } }\" }";

